# Converting inches into miles, feet, and inches

Tags: java

I must convert inches into miles. Then calculate the remaining feet after I calculate the miles. Then calculate the remaining inches after that. The output I'm getting is 19 miles, 19 feet, 7 inches when it should be 19 miles, 2560 feet, 7 inches.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author abc
 * @version 1-28-2014
 */

public class DistanceConverter   {


   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

      int numOfInches;

      System.out.print("Enter the raw measurement in inches: ");
      numOfInches = userInput.nextInt();

      if (numOfInches < 0)   {
         System.out.println("Measurement must be non-negative!");
      }

      int feet = numOfInches / 12;
      int miles = feet / 5280;
      int remainingFeet = miles % feet;
      int remainingInches = numOfInches % 12;

      if (numOfInches > 0)   {
         System.out.println("\n\nMeasurement by combined miles, feet, inches:");
         System.out.println("\tmiles: " + miles);
         System.out.println("\tfeet: " + remainingFeet);
         System.out.println("\tinches " + remainingInches);
         System.out.println("\n\n" + numOfInches + " inches = " + miles 
            + " miles, " + remainingFeet + " feet, " + remainingInches + " inches");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you not just debug it?

Comment: You need to take the modulus with the biggest unit of measurement (the mile) first, then remove that result from the TOTAL inches. So for a billion inches, take that modulo the number of inches in a mile, which gives you the number of miles. Subtract that number of inches from the total, then repeat for feet.

Comment: Hint: First find the miles, then feet, and so on.

Comment: Hint: Since the problem is in remainingFeet, look really carefully at the line that calculates it.

Comment: Hint: 'miles % feet' is a meaningless value.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 if( numOfInches > 0 ) {
   int inchesInFeet = 12;
   int feetsInMile = 5280;
   int inchesInMile = feetsInMile * inchesInFeet;
   int miles = numOfInches / inchesInMile;
   int remainingInches = numOfInches % inchesInMile;
   int feet = remainingInches / inchesInFeet;
   remainingInches = remainingInches % inchesInFeet;

   System.out.println( "\n\nMeasurement by combined miles, feet, inches:" );
   System.out.println( "\tmiles: " + miles );
   System.out.println( "\tfeet: " + feet );
   System.out.println( "\tinches " + remainingInches );
   System.out.println( "\n\n" + numOfInches + " inches = " + miles 
     + " miles, " + feet + " feet, " + remainingInches + " inches" );
 }
```